# Looking for SVN and bug tracker recommendations

Tags: windows, linux, svn, bug-tracking

We are starting a new software project. We are 5 developers, located in US and Asia.
We have a server hosted in the US and we plan to use it. We can set a SVN repository on it. It's a Linux server.

Our requirements are the following:

1. Windows good client. We develop on Windows (Visual Studio).
2. Private working space on Windows for each developer.
3. Good bug tracking. Integrating to SVN. Working on the server or on the client.

What do you suggest? Please specify names of SVN client and bug tracker.

If you are working in a similar approach - please specify pros & cons.

Answer (score 14):

TortoiseSVN is pretty good as a Windows SVN client.

Answer (score 14):

For the SVN clients, there are two you should consider:
* [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is a SVN client the has shell integration, meaning it itegrates with Windows Explorer.
* [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) intergrates with Visual Studio.
As far as I know, they are not mutually exclusive, so you could use both.

For the bug tracker with SVN integration, there are three free open source bug trackers you should look at:
* [BugTracker.NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) - which you'll have to run on a Windows machine.   (I'm the author of BugTracker.NET)
* [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)
* [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/)

Trac is very widely used.   The most common general criticism of it is that it is oriented to a [single project](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFaq#can-i-manage-multiple-projects-from-a-single-installation-of-trac).

Redmine was written to be a better Trac than Trac.   It handles multiple projects.   The most common general criticism of it is that it is very slow.

BugTracker.NET theoretically has its flaws, but it is very fast.   I've been using trac a bit hunting for old bugs in the Sourceforge.NET and CKEditor trackers, and I think the BugTracker.NET search is way, way better than Trac's.   So my personal complaint about Trac would be the weakness of its search.

If you want to explore commercial bug trackers that integrate with Subversion, then I'd start with [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/).

Comment: +1 for saying a few words about trac and making me giggle with "BugTracker.NET theoretically has its flaws, but it is very fast." :).

Answer (score 8):

Another thumbs up for [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).

I'd also recommend installing [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) which integrates with Tortoise. It's vastly superior to Tortoise's built in merge.

Answer (score 7):

I have always liked Trac.

Comment: fwiw, here's a link to Trac: http://trac.edgewall.org/

Answer (score 6):

Some of our developers had problems with [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), so now we use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) and [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) to integrate it with Visual Studio. The integration is not necessary if you take care when renaming and deling files, but I think it's nice to be able to do it directly in Visual Studio when you're refactoring class names and therefore renaming files.

Note that VisualSVN costs about 50 $ per license.

Answer (score 3):

For SVN client I would recommend [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).
For bug tracking [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/).

Comment: How do you configure tortoiseSvn with bugzilla?

Comment: Do you mean the integration of Subversion with Bugzilla? If so take a look at [Scmbug](http://freecode.com/projects/scmbug)

Comment: I am going to check this. seems promising

Answer (score 2):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/Features) has the features you need, plus project & document management, time tracking, forums and wiki.

As for SVN client, I also recommend TortoiseSVN.

EDIT: Redmine can be installed as a [VMWare appliance](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/1204), so setting it up should be easy.

Comment: I've used redmine in the past with excellent results.

Comment: +1 for Redmine. It does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: +1 for Redmine, we transitioned from Bugzilla and never looked back

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your exact needs I would recommend the following:

**Subversion Client**
Either [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), which integrates nicely with Windows Explorer or [Ankh SVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), which integrates nicely with Visual Studio.

**Bugtracker**
Most bugtrackers advised in this topic are free and/or open-source but since your question does not state that as a requirement I would suggest [Atlassian Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) or [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/) since they are (imo) definately the best bugtrackers around.

Answer (score 1):

Tortoise SVN is a great windows shell-based client.
Found problems with Ankh SVN (integration with visual studio).
As for bug tracking - OnTime is good and highly configurable (and has client exposure).

Comment: OnTime is probably the worst bug tracking system I've ever used, I'd have to recommend against it.  It's also not really clear how to integrate it with SVN.

Comment: We found it really useful in providing reporting for our PM's directly from the data updated by the dev's.  We got it to connect to SVN and link to bugs quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

As for Windows client you can use [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and if you want to use it straight from VS you have [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/). Tortoise integrates with Windows Explorer so it can work with any projects, Ankh can be a bit easier to use from Visual Studio as you won't have to switch to Windows Explorer to commit changes but it will work only with VS projects.

You can easily integrate SVN repository with Trac or JIRA. JIRA is more advanced but you have to buy it, trac is available for free.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look  @ [Jtrac](http://www.jtrac.info/)

we have been using this to track bugs in our small inhouse project.

Answer (score 0):

For SVN, [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and for bug tracking [onTime](http://www.axosoft.com) is good.
We are using the both right now. Ontime can't really integrate well with SVN. But as OnTime is full configurable, we have create custom svn revision field and fill it when we close an item. In the SVN clientSide, we add in the commit comment the ID of the item (bug or feature).

The advantage with onTime in comparison to a bugtracker like Bugzilla or BugTracker .Net is that OnTime isn't only a bug tracker. It's a Project Software Management. You can add your hours, generate report, buid wiki, he full supports Scrum with great burn down chart generation, adn so on.

Answer (score 0):

I had good experiences with tortoise and trac.  Now I am using three different installations of Fogbugz (2 free hosted and one at my full time job)

I have not used many other systems.

If you have the ability to spend money, I'd recommend fogbugz, otherwise go with trac, or the others recommended here.